# Uploading multiple pictures to R

Tags: r, image

I'm trying to upload multiple images to do some machine learning in R. I can upload a single image just fine, but when I try to upload multiple images using either lapply or a for loop, I get the following error: "Error in wrap.url(file, load.image.internal) : File not found". I did a check to make sure the files do exist, my WD is set correctly and R recognizes that the files and directory do exist. No matter what I change, the error is always the same. It doesn't change the outcome if I list the path from the drive it originates in or from the WD onward. I've asked many people for help with no success. I've posted my code using lapply and a for loop below. I'm still relatively new to R so if there is something I'm missing I'd greatly appreciate knowing. Also, I'm using imager here to load the files.

```
eggs2015 <- list() 
file_list <- list.files(path="~/Grad School/Thesis Work/Machine Learning R/a2015_experimental_clustering_R/*.jpg", pattern="*.jpg", full.names = TRUE)

for (i in 1:length(file_list)){                                           
  Path <- paste0("a2015_experimental_clustering_R",file_list[i])
  eggs2015 <- c(eggs2015, list(load.image(Path))) 
}

names(eggs2015) <- file_list
```

```
eggs2015 <- list.files(path = "~/Grad School/Thesis Work/Machine Learning R/2015_experimental_clustering_R", pattern = ".jpg", all.files = TRUE, full.names = TRUE)
eggs2015 <- lapply(list, FUN = load.image("~/Grad School/Thesis Work/Machine Learning R/a2015_experimental_clustering_R/*.jpg"))
eggs2015 <- as.data.frame(eggs2015)
```

Comment: Why do you create `eggs2015` with the names of files and then overwrite the variable without using it? `imager::load.image` returns an object, not a function, so you are using `lapply` incorrectly.

Comment: `lapply(list, FUN)` is (1) referencing a *variable* you named `list` (bad form, name collision with a base R function) and have not shared with us; (2) backwards, meaning you think the output from `load.image` should have the function `list` applied to all of its elements (unlikely); or (3) this is a typo, you intend `lapply(eggs2015, FUN=load.image)` (note that the function is a function name, not the result of a function call).

Answer (score 0):

Personally for this kind of operation I prefer to use `sapply` so I can identify images with the original file names later on (if needed):

```
FilesToRead <- list.files(path = "~/Grad School/Thesis Work/Machine Learning R/2015_experimental_clustering_R", pattern = ".jpg", all.files = TRUE, full.names = TRUE) 
ListOfImages <- sapply(FilesToRead, FUN = load.image, simplify = FALSE, USE.NAMES = TRUE)
```

should work and give you a list of elements with your images using the file paths as names

Or using `lapply` (`sapply` is just a wrapper for `lapply`)

```
ListOfImages <- lapply(FilesToRead, FUN = load.image)
```

As you can see, your code just needed a little tweaking.

Hope it helps